# Got a timeout error when I send an email using gmail:ClientConnector in ballerinalang

Tags: gmail-api, ballerina

I try to implement a program in ballerina to send an email using ballerina gmail:ClientConnector with gmail API. But it gives a timeout error like below.

```
error: ballerina.lang.errors:Error, message: failed to invoke 'post' action in ClientConnector. response was not received within sender timeout of 180 seconds
    at ballerina.net.http:ClientConnector.post(<native>:0)
    at org.wso2.ballerina.connectors.oauth2:ClientConnector.post(org/wso2/ballerina/connectors/oauth2/ClientConnector.bal:53)
    at org.wso2.ballerina.connectors.gmail:ClientConnector.sendMail(org/wso2/ballerina/connectors/gmail/gmailConnector.bal:631)
    at .:main(helloworld.bal:26)
```

And here is the code which I implement.

```
import org.wso2.ballerina.connectors.gmail;



function main (string[] args) {


    string clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    string clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    string userId = "webmisproject@gmail.com";
    string accessToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    string refreshToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    gmail:ClientConnector gmailConnector = create gmail:ClientConnector(userId,accessToken,refreshToken,clientId,clientSecret);

    string to = "b.wathsala.bw@gmail.com";
    string subject = "Test Mail";
    string from = "webmisproject@gmail.com";
    string messageBody = "Hello Buddhi";
    string cc = "";
    string bcc = "";
    string id = "";
    string threadId = "";
    message gmailResponse;


    gmailResponse = gmail:ClientConnector.sendMail(gmailConnector,to,subject,from,messageBody,cc,bcc,id,threadId);


}
```

I implement this code as in main function as well as a service in ballerina, but both give same error.As well it takes little bit time to give that error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem. I used UBUNTU 14.04. But when I run that code in UBUNTU 16.04 the issue was solved. So I think the problem is in UBUNTU 14.04. But I don't know what is the exact issue in UBUNTU 14.04.